# Rebase and change branch name in one step

Tags: git, version-control

Is it possible to rabase and rename a branch in one step? I have a branch named `add-some-stuff-to-4.6`. This branch starts from branch 4.6. I want to rebase `add-some-stuff-to-4.6` to `branch5.0` and rename it in `add-some-stuff-to-5.0`.

If this could not be possible, can I simply transfer all `add-some-stuff-to-4.6` commits to a new branch `add-some-stuff-to-5.0`?

Comment: You can use `git rebase ... && git branch -m new_name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On branch `add-some-stuff-to-4.6`, you can use:

`git branch -m add-some-stuff-to-4.6 add-some-stuff-to-5.0 & git rebase branch5.0`

All the commit histories in `add-some-stuff-to-4.6` before of cause will show in `add-some-stuff-to-5.0` branch.